# Configuring a dev machine to see PowerBI code demos (JSON support in Visual Studio 2015?)

Tags: json, powerbi

How do I install JSON support in Visual Studio 2015?

I saw a video by Satchin about how to prepare my PC, and installed Git and Node.JS without any problems, and everything was OK (I think; I'm not a web developer and I may be missing something) until i tried debugging (ctrl+f5) .

- when i enter visual studio, contrary to what Satchin said in the video, the application is not continuously integrating. My Task runner explorer has this info:

  ```
  Failed to run "C:\Users\L.Ricardo\Documents\GitHub\powerbi-visuals\Gulpfile.js"...
  cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
  Error: Cannot find module 'accord'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\L.Ricardo\Documents\GitHub\powerbi-visuals\node_modules\gulp-less\index.js:2:22)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  ```
- Javascript language reference has this info:

  ```
  11:30:09.2572: Referenced file 'C:\Users\L.Ricardo\Documents\GitHub\powerbi-visuals\src\Clients\PowerBIVisualsPlayground\externals.min.js' not found.
  11:30:09.2572: Referenced file 'C:\Users\L.Ricardo\Documents\GitHub\powerbi-visuals\src\Clients\PowerBIVisualsPlayground\powerbi-visuals.js' not found.
  11:30:09.2572: Referenced file 'C:\Users\L.Ricardo\Documents\GitHub\powerbi-visuals\src\Clients\PowerBIVisualsPlayground\PowerBIVisualsPlayground.js' not found.
  11:30:10.0229: Referenced file 'externals.min.js' not found.
  11:30:10.0229: Referenced file 'powerbi-visuals.js' not found.
  11:30:10.0229: Referenced file 'PowerBIVisualsPlayground.js' not found."
  ```

  (some info maybe from previous tries...)
- in the webpage, the dropdowns don't work. The error seems to be:

  ```
  0x800a1391 - runtime error JavaScript: '$' line 51 is not defined
  ```

...which I think means that I need to install JSON support.

So, how do I install JSON support in Visual Studio 2015?

Or is there some other reason for the problems I'm seeing?

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it you might have missed the "One Time setup" steps.  https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals

One-Time Setup

In order to build the Power BI visuals, ensure that you have Git and Node.js installed.

Clone a copy of the repo:
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals.git

Change to the PowerBI-visuals directory:
cd PowerBI-visuals

Install dev dependencies:
npm install  # This command will install Gulp and all necessary modules

Answer (score 0):

turns out there were happening errors when running npm install.

I executed npm cache clean and then npm install and now it's working!

Thanks